# Solving an iterative quadratic equation results in noise

Tags: c++

I am trying to solve a quadratic equation of the form:

$x^2 + 8.888e-5 x - (2.777e-6*t + 9.34694e-10) = 0$.

Where 't' is an iterative based variable. This resembles an exponential decay function. I tried to implement the same in C++ (Attached is the code). I can see the behavior/ trend however, at the end when the decay becomes smaller with respect to 't' I see some noise "wiggles" in the solution.

I  taught I could blame the precision of the compiler (5.4.0) but my friend argued using long double data types (e-10) values shall be accurate tough.

Attached is my Test.C below (use t_end as 0.03 and numTimeSteps as 4500 for example) and wiggles that I see. [image: Noise with the solution] Please use the "edit" file to plot with gnuplot. Can anyone hint me how to overcome this noise?

Test.C

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define PI 3.141592

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    long double t_start = 0.;               /*init time*/
    long double t_end;                      /*end time: user  specified*/
    int numTimeSteps;                       /*user specified*/
    long double dt;                         /*(t_end-t_start)/numTimeSteps*/
    cout << "Enter the end time, number of time steps between t_start and t_end" << endl;
    cin >> t_end >> numTimeSteps;
    dt = (t_end - t_start)/numTimeSteps;
    long double time[numTimeSteps]; 
    long double LHS[numTimeSteps];

    /*Terms of quadratic equation: ax^2 + bx + c =0
     * a and b are constants for test case */
    long double a = 1;
    long double b = 8.888e-5;

    long double determinant[numTimeSteps]; 

    long double root1[numTimeSteps], root2[numTimeSteps];
    long double xm[numTimeSteps];

    for (int i = 0; i <= numTimeSteps; i++)
    {
        time[i] = (t_start)+ (i*dt);
        /*Find LHS of equation based on time and other constants*/
        LHS[i] = -(2.777e-6*time[i]+9.34694e-10);

        cout << "Step = " << i << "\t" << time[i] << "\t" << LHS[i] << endl;

        /*Finding roots of Q.Eqn.
         *Find determinant and check for real roots less than 400e-6*/
        determinant[i] = pow(b,2) - 4.*a*LHS[i];
        cout << "Determinant [" << i << "] = " << determinant[i] << endl;

        /*Case1: Roots are real and equal*/
        if (determinant[i] == 0)    
        {
            root1[i] = root2[i] = -b/(2.*a);
            cout << "Determinant is 0: roots are real and equal" << endl;
            cout << root1[i] << endl;
            cout << "\t \t *** \t \t " << endl;
        } 
        /*Case2: Roots are real and different*/
        else if (determinant[i] > 0)
        {
            root1[i] = (-b+sqrt(determinant[i]))/(2.*a);
            root2[i] = (-b-sqrt(determinant[i]))/(2.*a);
            cout << "Determinant is > 0: roots are real and different" << endl;
            cout << "Root1 = " << root1[i] << " Root2 = " << root2[i] << endl;
            cout << "\t \t *** \t \t " << endl;
        }
        else  
            cout << "Determinant is < 0: roots are imaginary" << endl;
    } 

    for (int i = 1; i <= numTimeSteps; i++)
    {
        if (root1[i] > root1[i-1] && root1[i] < 400e-6)
            xm[i] = root1[i];
        else
            xm[i] = 0.;
        cout << "xm = " << xm[i] << endl; 
    }

    ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open("xm");

    if (myfile.is_open())
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= numTimeSteps; i++)
            myfile << time[i] << "\t" << xm[i] << endl;
        myfile.close();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

gnuplot's edit file to run:

```
#!/bin/bash

paste xm| awk '{print $1}' > TimeAllTest
paste xm| awk '{print $2}' > xmTest
awk 'NR>1{print $1-p}{p=$1}' TimeAllTest > dt
awk '{if (NR!=1) {print}}' TimeAllTest > Time
awk 'NR>1{print $1-p}{p=$1}' xmTest > dxmTest
paste Time dt dxmTest | awk '{print $1, ($3/$2)}' > tvsuTest
```

Thanks.

Comment: @hnefatl: Please stop adding your equation picture. Your equation does not correspond to what the OP posted.

Comment: @NicoSchertler Ah yeah, that is my bad - forgot that `e` literals are base 10 exponents in C++... I'll re-edit to just include the code formatting and skip out the equation image.

Comment: Your code calculates `x` as a function of `t`.   If you differentiate that function (easy enough to do by hand) you'll be able to see if the presence of "wiggles" is a real effect - if it is, the derivative will have zero values and change sign.

Comment: @peter the wiggles are an artifact (this is occurs when the xm changes slower wrt time on the X-axis). I was thinking it is due to floating point computation but the compiler shall be able to handle (atleast as I am using long double for this reason). I see nothing strange with the code. It is a continuous decay with no change in sign.

Comment: Though Wintermute has identified the main issue, a couple more points: Finding the derivative of a function by subtracting nearby values is usually a bad idea, because subtracting two similar numbers is the worst for floating point precision issues.  If you have interest in the "dxm" data itself, rather than just trying to see how accurate (or not) your "xm" data is, you should instead work out the derivative of the function on paper and implement that equation directly.

Comment: And for the same reason, the `+` sign in `(-b+sqrt(determinant[i]))/(2.*a)` destroys some precision.  You might get more accurate results for some inputs if you compute `root1 = c*a/root2;` whenever `a*b<0` (with `root2` computed as you did), and `root2 = c*a/root1;` whenever `a*b>0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a problem with output precision. The `xm` file your program generates contains lines such as

```
0.0299933 0.00469697
```

so most of the long double mantissa is already lost there. Moreover, the awk script also prints with awk's default precision, causing the same problem again later down the line.

Putting

```
myfile.open("xm");
myfile.precision(20); // 20 digits of precision in output
```

into the C++ program and changing the awk script like so:

```
#!/bin/bash

paste xm| awk '{print $1}' > TimeAllTest
paste xm| awk '{print $2}' > xmTest

# Note: printf instead of print
awk 'NR>1{ printf("%.20f\n", $1-p) }{p=$1}' TimeAllTest > dt
awk '{if (NR!=1) {print}}' TimeAllTest > Time
awk 'NR>1{printf("%.20f\n", $1-p) }{p=$1}' xmTest > dxmTest
paste Time dt dxmTest | awk '{ printf("%.20f %.20f\n", $1, ($3/$2)) }' > tvsuTest
```

fixes the problem:

[image]

You may also want to consider using `sqrtl` instead of `sqrt` (or `std::sqrt` explicitly). I think the way it is now, depending on gcc 5.4's libstdc++ header structure, the old `sqrt` C function may be used, and that uses `double` values instead of `long double` values. The same goes for `pow`/`powl`/`std::pow`, although there I'd really just use `b * b`.

Comment: oh wow!! I just hitting around that point but not sure how to set the precision. Thanks for that!!